# Year and week to timeformat "ddmmmyyyy"

Tags: sas

I have a variable in SAS with a specificed year, called "year", and a specified week of the year,"week". Based on this, I want to create a time variable as "ddmmmyyyy", where dd should always be 01.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think INTCK is a reasonable approach.

```
24         data _null_;
25            do year = 2015;
26               ref = mdy(01,01,year);
27               do week = 0,1 to 50 by 5,52;
28                  week_starts = intnx('WEEK',ref,week,'B');
29                  week_ends   = intnx('WEEK',ref,week,'E');
30                  put (week year ref week_:)(2*=best. 3*=date9.);
31                  end;
32               end;
33            run;

week=0 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=28DEC2014 week_ends=03JAN2015
week=1 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=04JAN2015 week_ends=10JAN2015
week=6 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=08FEB2015 week_ends=14FEB2015
week=11 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=15MAR2015 week_ends=21MAR2015
week=16 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=19APR2015 week_ends=25APR2015
week=21 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=24MAY2015 week_ends=30MAY2015
week=26 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=28JUN2015 week_ends=04JUL2015
week=31 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=02AUG2015 week_ends=08AUG2015
week=36 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=06SEP2015 week_ends=12SEP2015
week=41 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=11OCT2015 week_ends=17OCT2015
week=46 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=15NOV2015 week_ends=21NOV2015
week=52 year=2015 ref=01JAN2015 week_starts=27DEC2015 week_ends=02JAN2016
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert week into month and then use mdy() function.

```
format new ddmmmyyyy.; **or try date.;
month=year*365+week*7-'1jan60'd;  **should be a sas date;
new=mdy(month(month),1,year);
```

Comment: Perhaps because your requirement doesn't make sense.  I think you mean DD should always be the first day of the WEEK not 01

Comment: Sorry Dirk I thought the OP was asking about down voting.  I don't know why your answer was down voted.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are due to using 365 hardcoded (inaccurate) rather than the `intnx()` function with the `'year'` interval (accurate).

Comment: What does subtracting 0 ('01jan1060'd)do?